# IPython - Raise exception when a shell command fails

Tags: ipython

I'm using [IPython as a system shell](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/interactive/shell.html).

Is there a way to make IPython to raise an exception when the shell command fails? (non-zero exit codes)

The default makes them fail silently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of `IPython` 4.0.1, `!cmd` is transformed into `get_ipython().system(repr(cmd))` (`IPython.core.inputtransformer._tr_system()`).
In the source, it's actually `InteractiveShell.system_raw()`, as `inspect.getsourcefile()` and `inspect.getsource()` can tell.

It delegates to `os.system()` in Windows and `subprocess.call()` in other OSes. Not configurable, as you can see from the code.

So, you need to replace it with something that would call `subprocess.check_call()`.

Apart from monkey-patching by hand, this can be done with the [IPython configuration system](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/config/intro.html#setting-configurable-options). Available options (viewable with the `%config` magic) don't allow to replace `TerminalInteractiveShell` with another class but several `TerminalIPythonApp` options allow to execute code on startup.

Do double-check whether you really need this though: a look through the `system_raw()`'s source reveals that it sets the `_exit_code` variable - so it doesn't actually fail *completely* silently.

Comment: This answer describes a lot of details on the implementation but doesn't actually propose a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `!` to execute shell commands, errors will pass silently

```
!echo "hello" && exit 1
```

```
hello
```

If you use the `%%sh` cell magic to execute the shell command, errors will raise:

```
%%sh
echo "hello" && exit 1
```

```
hello
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-9229f76cae28> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('sh', '', 'echo "hello" && exit 1\n')

~/anaconda/envs/altair-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2360             with self.builtin_trap:
   2361                 args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2362                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2363             return result
   2364 

~/anaconda/envs/altair-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in named_script_magic(line, cell)
    140             else:
    141                 line = script
--> 142             return self.shebang(line, cell)
    143 
    144         # write a basic docstring:

<decorator-gen-110> in shebang(self, line, cell)

~/anaconda/envs/altair-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/anaconda/envs/altair-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in shebang(self, line, cell)
    243             sys.stderr.flush()
    244         if args.raise_error and p.returncode!=0:
--> 245             raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, cell, output=out, stderr=err)
    246 
    247     def _run_script(self, p, cell, to_close):

CalledProcessError: Command 'b'echo "hello" && exit 1\n'' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```