# ipython - force executing of expression in any cursor position

Tags: python, terminal, ipython

I have ipython 5.3.0 and when i am in the middle of expression (cursor is marked as `<cursor>`), for example:

```
In [69]: x = np.arange(<cursor>1, 21, 2).reshape(2, 5)
```

Than pressing enter causes split this line into two lines.

```
In [69]: x = np.arange(                       
    ...: 1, 21, 2).reshape(2, 5)
```

But when i have cursor in other place for example:

```
 In [69]: x = np.<cursor>arange(1, 21, 2).reshape(2, 5)
```

It executes expression.

Which keyboard shortcut forces execution of expression without taking care of cursor position?

I tried CTRL + ENTER or SHIFT + ENTER but no one of them working for first example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forcing IPython to execute the current multiline code block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863295/forcing-ipython-to-execute-the-current-multiline-code-block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This was fixed in `IPython 5.4`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10425). Earlier, there's no way short of patching/[monkey-patching at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857230/ipython-raise-exception-when-a-shell-command-fails/35857872#35857872), but there's an easy workaround.

Here's the relevant logic from `5.4.1`, in `IPython/terminal/shortcuts.py`. The fragment with a comment referring to the issue on the first link is the fix.

```
def newline_or_execute_outer(shell):
    def newline_or_execute(event):
        """When the user presses return, insert a newline or execute the code."""
        b = event.current_buffer
        d = b.document

        if b.complete_state:
            cc = b.complete_state.current_completion
            if cc:
                b.apply_completion(cc)
            else:
                b.cancel_completion()
            return

        # If there's only one line, treat it as if the cursor is at the end.
        # See https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10425
        if d.line_count == 1:
            check_text = d.text
        else:
            check_text = d.text[:d.cursor_position]
        status, indent = shell.input_splitter.check_complete(check_text + '\n')

        if not (d.on_last_line or
                d.cursor_position_row >= d.line_count - d.empty_line_count_at_the_end()
                ):
            b.insert_text('\n' + (' ' * (indent or 0)))
            return

        if (status != 'incomplete') and b.accept_action.is_returnable:
            b.accept_action.validate_and_handle(event.cli, b)
        else:
            b.insert_text('\n' + (' ' * (indent or 0)))
    return newline_or_execute
```

As you can see, the action depends on the cursor's position relevant to a code's token.

So, if you have a complete statement, you can force execution by simply pressing <kbd>End</kbd> before <kbd>Enter</kbd>.