# Forcing IPython to execute the current multiline code block

Tags: python, ipython

In IPython (7.3.0), I can edit a multiline code block:

```py
In [1]: def funtcion(a, b):
   ...:     return a + b
   ...:
```

I then realize that I've made a typo, which I want to correct (`|` marks the location of the cursor):

```py
<press up arrow, then edit>
In [2]: def funct|ion(a, b):
   ...:     return a + b
   ...:
```

I want to execute that:

```py
<press enter>
In [2]: def funct
   ...: |ion(a, b):
   ...:     return a + b
   ...:
```

...which doesn't really do what I want.

Is there a way to force IPython to execute the current cell?

Comment: go to the end of the block using the arrow keys then press enter on an empty line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @AntiMatterDynamite has mentioned in the comments, you could navigate to the end of the block and then hit `Enter`. But (for me, at least) that seems to miss the point.

Instead, try hitting `Shift`+`Enter` mid line, which should execute the current cell regardless of cursor position. This has always worked for me in Spyder's IPython console.

Interestingly, when I tested hitting `Shift`+`Enter` in a regular IPython console (ie. IPython initialised from the terminal, not from Spyder) it didn't work. However, hitting `Esc` followed by `Enter` did work.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I tried a lot of shortcuts but not this one!

Comment: If `ESC Enter` works `Alt Enter` may work too. Usually `ESC` is interchangeable with `Alt` but not always. In this case it worked for me, Thanks!

Comment: On a MacBook no combination of ⌘, ⌥, ⌃ or ⇧ worked, but `ESC` then ⏎ worked.

Comment: @geckos Interesting, I did not know that!

Comment: I have to use Alt+Enter on ubuntu.